# How to enable scrolling through keyboard and mouse in SENCHA webApp?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd, sencha-touch-2.1

I want to do scrolling using keyboard and mouse in Sencha WebApp just like we do in other websites.
One way is to add eventListener and track it do the movement of views. But it would make it very difficult to handle. As there are many views in App.

Comment: I thought if the view extends the size of displayed page, scroll bars automatically appear. This also depends on how you have laid out your views. Look for the Layout property, it plays a vital role in scrolling.

Comment: The qus is how to make sure scrolling happens through track ball or keyboard up down keys. Not by holding the scrollbar and scroll it.

Comment: FYI your question doesnt mention that.. Also If scrollbar appears, then I dont see why trackball or key board wouldnt work.